# How can I point my domain name to my nodejs application on VPS server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vps

I have:

1. React Application work on `localhost:3000` ( VPS Server )
2. `DomainName.com`

What do I have to know if I want to access my React Application from everywhere using `DomainName.com`?

Comment: You'll have to set your DNS settings for the public IP of your VPS server to be able to access your application from that domain name.

Comment: Do you have a example of this solutions ?

Comment: MAybe you can take a look here: https://www.photonvps.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=30

Comment: I done with A record settting but i don't know to setup DNS on vps server side.

Comment: In case you don't want to setup your own DNS server, many VPS providers also provide a DNS server that you can use (you might want to consult the documentation or ask the tech. support) or you can easily find a DNS service provider that suits your needs (free options exist.) You'll also need to bind the web server to the public IP address of your VPS (and maybe change the port.)